# jquery Chosen Higlight option in Multiselect

Tags: jquery, highlight, jquery-chosen

in the great jquery Chosen plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
is it possible to highlight an option within an multiselect.
An image will say more than a description:[image]

EDIT:
Sorry for the unclear question. It would be great if the highlight fires by a givven attribute in the option tag. f.e. a class name or a "name"

```
<option value="xyz" selected="selected" class="active" name="active">item</option>
```

Thanks,

t book

Comment: On what basis and event you want to highlight the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**CSS**

```
.active{
    background : #FF0 !important;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("select").chosen().change(function(){
    $('li.search-choice').removeClass('active');
    $('li.search-choice:last').addClass('active');
});
```

[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/c23Qy/)

Comment: Hi thanks for this! Do I have any chance to fire the add class not on change but on an attribute which my option has? f.e. a "name" or a class? (class will not be that simple because chosen replaces them)

Comment: Thanks, I´ve change this solution a bit to find the option with :contains selector and give this the active class

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like what you are looking for with css:

```
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice.emphasize {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FFEDB5 20%, #FFAE03 50%, #E09B1F 52%, #DBAD4B 100%);
    background-color: #C9AB11;
}
```

The only other thing you would need to do is select the element you want to highlight and emphasize by adding the class `emphasize`. To highlight requires some code I haven't shown but it shouldn't be too hard to create. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to color the last multiselect menu. You can use:

```
$('ul.chosen-choices .search-choice:last span').css('background-color','yellow')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toogleClass like in this working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vV4CU/)**.

Like:

```
$('#target').toggleClass('toggled');
```

and in your css, use different color for element with toggled class.